# Microsoft SQL Server does not return everything when using LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, sql-server-2014-express

I have a `Products` table in SQL Server 2014 Express with records in it.

A few product names (records) are the following:

- Test product
- Teszt termék
- Teszt termék 2

When I execute the following query, everything works just fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE name LIKE 'te%'
```

It retrieves all three records. However, when I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE name LIKE 'tes%'
```

is executed, only "Test product" is retrieved. And when the query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE name LIKE 'tesz%'
```

then it works again, it fetches all the records starting with "Tesz".

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: it's working with the given data and select query

Comment: is it a `NVARCHAR`?, if so, you should be using `WHERE name LIKE N'tes%'` instead

Comment: its type is varchar(255)

Comment: Then I don't see why this isn't working as it should

Comment: change the input language to which the data is in, and type `'tes%'` again

Comment: No repro: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cbee/2

Comment: here's a link to download the backup file of the database if you'd like to check it out: http://www.megafileupload.com/1jzK/Database

Comment: I seriously doubt that someone will download your database to help you with this.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it's caused by wrong collation?

Comment: Yep. Collation http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz_(digraph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your backup.

The database collation is set to `Hungarian_CI_AS`.

Sz is treated as a letter in its own right in Hungarian ([the thirty-second letter of the Hungarian alphabet](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz_(digraph))). If you do not want this behaviour then you need to avoid Hungarian collations and it should work. (I tested all SQL Server 2014 collations with names ending `CI_AS` and the only ones showing the behaviour are `Hungarian_CI_AS`, `Hungarian_100_CI_AS`, `SQL_Hungarian_CP1250_CI_AS`)

You can do this either by altering the column collation (preferable) or by adding an explicit `COLLATE` clause to the query (less efficient and will block  queries such as `WHERE name LIKE 'tes%'` being resolved through an index seek).

You might also consider changing the database collation but this will not cascade through to pre-existing table columns created on the old collation.